# Can I replace my furnace's high limit switch with a comparable third-party part?

Tags: hvac, furnace, air-conditioning

I have an older Lennox furnace.  The high limit switch (#60T15,130F) has gone bad.  I haven't been able to find on-line this part number with the exact temp limit specs, and Lennox no longer carries this part either.  Do I have to use this particular limit switch, or can I replace it with something similar?

Comment: I'd contact your local Lennox installer, they might have the part on hand, or know what replacement part should be used. If they can't help, contact Lennox directly and ask them what replacement part to use. When it comes to safety limits, you want to make sure you use the correct parts

Comment: I did contact Lennox.  The do not have the part and no replacement was given.

Comment: Did you specifically ask them for a recommended replacement part?

Comment: Can you include some photos of the part? Is it manual reset? If so, did you press the reset button? What's the model number of the furnace?

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced over temp switches in the past because the one that failed was no longer made.
I used a slightly low temp rating as the exact temp was not available. Most over temp switches are manual reset. 
This is a safety so if there is something wrong you have to reset it by pressing a small button on the switch.
Don’t replace with an automatic reset because this can damage the fire box and possibly start a fire.

Answer (score -2):

Theres a reason why it trips on safety: to protect you. The reason why they don't sell that part is so they won't be liable if the real reason it tripped was a cracked heat exchanger. Now I bet they'll sell you one of those for $200 or so...